# Why would a Linux device be ping-able using a direction connection but not ping-able when plugged into a switch?

Tags: linux, switch

I’m currently using a linux based device with an NTRON 716TX managed switch ([manual here](https://www.redlion.net/sites/default/files/213/4174/700%20Series%20Product%20Manual.pdf)). I’m running into an issue where I’m unable to ping the linux device through this switch, even though all my network settings seem to be correct. I’ve confirmed the following:

- I can ping the linux device directly from my PC which should prove the subnet mask and IP addresses are good.
- I’m able to ping another device through the switch from my PC which proves the switch is somewhat functional.
- I've putty'd into the device serially and confirmed that I can’t ping either my PC or other devices from the linux device.
- I’ve verified that there are no IP address conflicts.
- I've verified there are no bad cables/unplugged, etc.

My efforts suggest the linux device is not playing nice with the switch. However, I've exhausted all of my troubleshooting and still have not found the problem.

I'm curious if anyone could offer insight into what the problem may be.

I'm also curious if anyone is aware of further troubleshooting techniques for linux computers. Like I said, I can serially log into the device and try to ping other devices on the network, this could potentially be useful for trying to find log files to debug.

One last thing, I'm somewhat confused on what the default gateway route should be if I do not have a gateway on the network. Can the default gateway be a non-existing device (i.e. dummy address), must it be set to the device IP address, or should there be no default gw route listed?

Comment: Are there any vlan configurations on the switch that would prevent the traffic from being passed between ports?

Comment: @Safado It does not appear that this switch has any VLAN configurations.